# Insert char to List<string>

Tags: c#, list, insert

Is it possible to insert char to List?

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>()
{
   "mobilePhone",
   "CoffeeMachine"
};
```

I would like insert " " at index [0][6] and [1][6] but when I use this:

```
arr[0].Insert(6," ");
```

It returns a new string that is equivalent to this instance but I need to save it at the same list.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Overwrite your list element.

Comment: I'm torn between trying to find a better duplicate for this, marking this as a typo, and making an answer saying "just do `arr[0] = <your existing line>`".

Comment: Right now I feel like the question is unclear. If you modify a string, by definition, it _cannot_ be equivalent to the original string. That said, the OP also said they need to save it to the same list, which seems unrelated to .Insert. At this point in time, I think the question probably needs to be closed unless clarified.